# spreadsheetgear+how to display built in page setup dialog

Tags: vb.net, spreadsheetgear

I tried to select/display the builtin pagesetup dialog highlighting the pagesetup tab in 'spreadsheetgear workbook explorer' window. In the .exe provided by spreadsheetgear, it is shown but not in the sample code provided by them, can anyone from the expert group who uses the spreadsheetgear advice me how to select the specific tab in the workbook explorer of spreadsheetgear through code.

Comment: This question is not stated as clearly as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pre-select a particular "Page Setup" node for a particular worksheet in the TreeView of the [Workbook Explorer dialog](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookExplorer.html) when you instantiate this dialog yourself, i.e., something like...

```
WorkbookExplorer explorerDialog = new WorkbookExplorer(workbookView.ActiveWorkbookSet);
//explorerDialog.SelectPageSetupNode(...);  // This API doesn't exist.
explorerDialog.Show();
```

[image]

...then this is not possible, as there are no public APIs to do this.

The `SpreadsheetGear2017ForWindows.exe` application can do this because it has access to internal APIs to make such a selection.  We do collect feature requests to expose public APIs to perform such tasks (I work for SpreadsheetGear), so I can add one for you, although I cannot comment on if or when such a feature would be added to our product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim.. If I need such feature,certainly I will make a request.